# Digitar a senha do sudo após rodar comando spawn

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando fazer um *script* em Node.js para atualizar meu computador.

Estou usando `child_process.spawn`.

Ao digitar `sudo apt update`, ele fica esperando a senha. Já tentei informar com `stdin.write`, mas não tive sucesso.

PS: Tem que ser com sudo.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    app.post('/update',cors(), function (req, res) {
        let command = `sudo apt udpate'`
        const cmd = spawn(command,[], { shell: true });

        cmd.stdin.write("minhasenha\n");


        cmd.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            // cmd.stdin.write("minhasenha");
            console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

O `sudo` acessa diretamente o tty ao qual está conectado para receber a senha, e por isso não adianta você escrevê-la no `stdin`.

Para contornar isso você pode adicionar uma permissão no arquivo `sudoers` para executar o comando desejado sem senha:

1. execute o comando `visudo`
2. adicione a linha `seu-usuário ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/apt`
3. salve a alteração e feche o editor

Após isso o `seu-usuário` poderá executar o comando `sudo apt <argumentos>` sem nunca mais pedir da senha.

Se modificar o `sudoers` não for possível, você pode usar o argumento `--askpass` mais a variável de ambiente `SUDO_ASKPASS` para especificar um comando que forneceria a senha via `stdout`.